# Searching after filtering, AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, loops, search

I'm using ui-select to create a multiple select that can be searched, but I think this problem can be replicated in any ng-repeat-like structure.

I have an array of languageIsoCodes, like this:

```
[es, en, it, ca, ar, af, al, fr]
```

I have a repeat looping this array with a filter to display the full-name of the language, for example: es -> Spanish

The problem is that I want that loop to be searchable, but when I'm typing, it only matches the isoCodes, and not the filtered words. Is there a way to search over the filtered loop?

```
<ui-select ng-model="vmDetails.stepDetails.sourceLanguageIsoCode" theme="selectize" title="Select a Language" required on-select="vmDetails.filterLanguages()">
  <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a Language">{{$select.selected|languages}} ({{$select.selected}})</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices  repeat="sourceLanguageIsoCode as sourceLanguageIsoCode in vmDetails.selectedSource | filter: $select.search">
    <span>{{sourceLanguageIsoCode|languages}} ({{sourceLanguageIsoCode}})</span>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

A visual example: 
[image]

Comment: I guess that first, the user should be select the language and after execute the filter when starting to type on the input